# Can I use Raven's management studio on port 80 when it is embedded in an MVC 3 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, shared-hosting, ravendb

I am using ravendb 1.0.531 in an MVC 3 app to store my data.

I'd like to use the built in HTTP server to view my data. Everything works fine on port 8080 in my localhost. On production it doesn't work because it is on port 8080. Is there a way to make Ravendb work with MVC 3 so MVC 3 can run on port 80 and send the raven requests to Raven MGMT studio?

Here is my code:

```
 var returnStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore();
 returnStore.DataDirectory = @"./PersistedData";
 returnStore.UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true;
 returnStore.Configuration.Port = 80;
 returnStore.Initialize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,
RavenDB uses an abstraction for HTTP layer, so I guess you could write something that would redirect that. But it would be much easier to do that if you are hosting RavenDB as a virtual directory, instead.

Comment: Oops, I had the wrong port in my posted code last night. I've updated it now. I want it to run on port 80 like the rest of the website. I'll assume your answer still applies unless I hear otherwise.